# Move to the Facebook application page after authenticate through Single Sign On

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am working on an application where I need to integrate the social functionality of Facebook.

What I want is to use the SSO(Single Sign On) functionality and when the user press a button in my app, a webview will open and show him my app page in Facebook, after the user authenticated and now he could do like of other things as authenticated user.

I downloaded the Facebook SDK and includes it in my project, I also signed my application in the Facebook developers page and get an APP-ID.

This is how my code looks like till now:

```
public class WebViewLike extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "WebViewLike";
    public static final String APP_ID = "1222222";
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    private WebView webView;
    private Activity myActivity;

    private final class WallWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {
            myActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            myActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                myActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_weblike);
        myActivity = this;

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook.getAccessToken() " + facebook.getAccessToken());
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook.getAccessExpires() " + facebook.getAccessExpires()); 

                //Load the given URL
                webView.loadUrl(getFacebookWallUrl());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");}
        });

        initWebView();
    }

    private void initWebView() {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.likeWebView );
        final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); 
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WallWebChromeClient());
    }

    private String getFacebookWallUrl() {

        Log.d(TAG, "facebook.getAccessToken() != null");
        String wallUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login.php?" + "href="
                + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.facebook.com/MyAppPage") + "&access_token="
                + URLEncoder.encode(facebook.getAccessToken());

        Log.d(TAG, "wallUrl " + wallUrl);
        return wallUrl;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

For now when I press the button, I move to a new activity that says that I'm already authorized, what means that the SSO works fine. The problem is when I press the Okay button, as I said, I want to move to my app page, but all the things I tried show me my Facebook application page, but asks me to login again. From my point of view I need to change the beginning of the `wallUrl` string at the `getFacebookWallUrl()` method, but I can't find any information about it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sharing something about your app through social network? If your answer is yes then try [this](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381271-addthis-for-android-quickstart-guide#.T-Gl1PXeDIU).

Comment: Not sharing anything, just want the user see my application page and that he have the ability to do like or other things, like read comments or post comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fbrocket api for Facebook integration like the following example. I am using it successfully.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket/#idc-cover

Comment: I don't want to post status, I just want to show to the user my facebook page, without any login needed. From what I see fbrocket is for post status. Thanks.